# Is there a way to manage part of an Entity Framework object using EF and the remainder using ADO?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have to maintain an application that creates and manages quotations. (A quotation is a single class containing all information needed for pricing).

Most of the time, creating a quotation means adding a couple of lines to a couple of tables. It is pretty fast. Sometime however, the user attaches a large history of claims to the quotation and tens of thousands lines must be created in the database. Using EF, it takes forever.

So I've tried to use DbBulkCopy to bulk insert the claims while using EF to manage the reminder of the quotation, but the way I figure out how to achieve this is really, really cumbersome: I had to clone the quotation, detach the histories, delete the claims from the database, save the quotation, get the new foreign keys, bulk create the claims, attach the histories back to the quotation, etc.

Is it another way to achieve this?

Note: I could separate the claim history from the Quotation class and manage the first using ADO and the later using EF, but a lot of existing processes need the actual class design (not to mention that the user can actually attach many claim histories, which, of course, are sub-collections of sub-collections of sub-collections buried deep in the object tree...).

Many thanks in advance,
Sylvain.

Comment: It's posible to try a stored procedure approach?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I would have to save the whole object using the stored procedure as far as I know. And as Giorgio pointed out, I would then loose the advantage of using an ORM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to accomplish this :

```
// We will need a quotation Id (see below). Make sure we have one
SaveQuotation( myQuotation );

// Read the large claim history 
var claimCollection = ImportClaimsFromExcelFile( fileName );

// Save the claim history without using EF. The quotation Id is needed to 
// link the history to the quotation.
SaveClaimCollectionUsingSqlBulkCopy( claimCollection, myQuotation.Id );

// Now, ask EF to reload the quotation.
LoadQuotation( myQuotation.Id );
```

With an history of 60 000 claims, **this code runs in 10 seconds**. Using `myObjectContext.SaveChanges()`, 10 minutes were not even enough...

Thanks for your suggestions!

Note : Here is the code I used to bulk insert the claims :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copy.DestinationTableName = "ImportedLoss";
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add("ImporterId", "ImporterId");
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Loss", "Loss");
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add("YearOfLoss", "YearOfLoss");
        copy.BatchSize = 1000;
        copy.WriteToServer(dt); 
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the many round-trips made to the db in order to persist an entity, EF is not the best choice for bulk operations. This said looks like the EF team is looking into improving this http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/53

Also, have a look here : http://elegantcode.com/2012/01/26/sqlbulkcopy-for-generic-listt-useful-for-entity-framework-nhibernate/.
Another possible solution could be add all your Inserts within a single **ExecuteSqlCommand**, but then you will be loosing all the advantages of using an ORM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution (a single sql command) would work, but as you wrote it, I would loose the advantages of EF. And I cannot wait for the next EF version :) Cheers.